# Connect $4n$ points along a circle in a rotationally symmetric way

Tags: combinatorics

Given $4n$ equally spaced points along a circle, I would like to show that there are exactly $\binom{2n}n$ ways to connect them using non-intersecting arcs in such a way that the resulting configuration is symmetric under a rotation of 180 degrees.

This is just a conjecture of mine, so it might be incorrect; if so, please say so!

At any rate, I think I have an inductive proof of this. Basically, fix a point and consider all $2n$ possible points which it could go to. (Note: There are only $2n$ possible ones because the two half-disks which this arc encloses both need evenly many points, otherwise we don't get a valid configuration.) Then consider the rotated version of this arc. We thus get three components bounded by the two arcs and the circle. Then we just do casework.

Does anyone have a non-inductive proof though? I'd love for a purely combinatorial argument!

Comment: @Aqua Yes, I already proved it in fact. But I’m hoping for a combinatorial proof!

Comment: Presumably this means $4n$ equally spaced points?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Oh yes, you’re right! I’ll edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number the points from $1$ to $4n$ consecutively, and consider the set $S$ of points numbered $1$ to $2n$. For each point $x\in S$, when you move from $x$ to its partner along the shortest route on the perimeter, you move either clockwise or anti-clockwise. Let $$A=\{x\in S\mid \text{$x$'s partner is anti-clockwise from $x$}\}.$$ I claim two things:

- $|A|=n$, for all possible symmetric matchings
- For every $B\subseteq S$ with $|B|=n$, there is exactly one matching where $A=B$.

Once you prove these facts, it is clear that the number of matchings is $\binom{2n}n$, since you can specify a matching by choosing what $A$ is. The first point is not too bad to prove. For the second, see [Computing fixpoints of noncrossing matchings of $2n$ points under rotation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913242/177399), where I answer a generalization of your question, counting matchings which are invariant under rotation by other angles.